# how to make link which use only once in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

How to make Signed route invalid after use means how to make link which use only once

current code is like below

```
URL::signedRoute('email.verify', ['id' => $user->id], now()->addMinutes(30))
```

Comment: SignedRoute does not have that feature, but include your email verify logic and maybe we can tweek that to be one time use

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below logic as per your requirement.

Generate a temporary signed route URL that expires, you may use the temporarySignedRoute method

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

return URL::temporarySignedRoute(
  'email/verify', now()->addMinutes(30), ['user' => 1]
);
```

To verify that an incoming request has a valid signature, you should call the **hasValidSignature** method on the incoming Request.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get('/email/verify/{user}', function (Request $request) {
    if (!$request->hasValidSignature()) {
        abort(401);
    }

// ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at how the framework does this for the temporary signed route for the initial user verification email. You should see it can be quite easy for your case too.

Framework:

```
   /**
     * Get the verification URL for the given notifiable.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return string
     */
    protected function verificationUrl($notifiable)
    {
        return URL::temporarySignedRoute(
            'verification.verify',
            Carbon::now()->addMinutes(Config::get('auth.verification.expire', 60)),
            [
                'id' => $notifiable->getKey(),
                'hash' => sha1($notifiable->getEmailForVerification()),
            ]
        );
    }
```

Yours:

```
URL::temporarySignedRoute(
    'email.verify',
     now()->addMinutes(30),
    ['id' => $user->id],
);
```